# PHP + HTML HOTEL FORM

Tags: php, html

HTML

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">

  <table width="450px">

    <tr>

      <td valign="top" ">

        <label for="first_name ">First Name *</label>

      </td>

      <td valign="top">

        <input type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">

      </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

      <td valign="top">

        <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>

      </td>

      <td valign="top ">

        <input type="text " name="last_name " maxlength="50 " size="30 ">

      </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

      <td valign="top ">

        <label for="email ">Email Address *</label>

      </td>

      <td valign="top ">

        <input type="text " name="email " maxlength="80 " size="30 ">

      </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

      <td valign="top ">

        <label for="telephone ">Telephone Number</label>

      </td>

      <td valign="top ">

        <input type="text " name="telephone " maxlength="30 " size="30 ">

      </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

      <td valign="top ">

        <label for="comments ">Comments *</label>

      </td>

      <td valign="top ">

        <textarea name="comments " maxlength="1000 " cols="25 " rows="6 "></textarea>

      </td>

    </tr>


    <tr>

      <td valign="top ">

        <label for="room ">Room</label>

        <td valign="top ">
          <select>
            <option value="Ηλεκτρολογοι ">Type room 1</option>
            <option value="Γεωπονοι ">Tyre room 2</option>

          </select>


        </td>

        <td valign="top ">




        </td>

    </tr>



    <tr>

      <td colspan="2 " style="text-align:center ">





        <input type="image " src="buttononclick.png " alt="Submit Form " />

      </td>

    </tr>

  </table>

</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {



    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

    $email_to = "antonis997@gmail.com";

    $email_subject = "Your email subject line";





    function died($error) {

        // your error code can go here

        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

        echo $error."<br /><br />";

        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

        die();

    }



    // validation expected data exists

    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['email']) ||

        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||

        !isset($_POST['comments'])  ||

        !isset($_POST['room']))  { 

        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       

    }



    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required

    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required

    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required

    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $room = $_POST['room']; // not required



    $error_message = "errrror1";

    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {

    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    died($error_message);

  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }



    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Room: ".clean_string($room)."\n";





// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>



<!-- include your own success html here -->



Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.



<?php

}

?>
```

I the problem is the "room" value doesn't work , i have checked it all the other one works perfect but not the last one!
I want help

Comment: What do you mean it "doesn't work"? What about it "doesn't work"? What constitutes a "working" state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add the name of the field to the select element

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">

<table width="450px">

    <tr>

      <td valign="top">

        <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>

      </td>

      <td valign="top">

        <input type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">

      </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

      <td valign="top">

        <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>

      </td>

      <td valign="top">

        <input type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">

      </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

      <td valign="top">

        <label for="email ">Email Address *</label>

      </td>

      <td valign="top">

        <input type="text " name="email " maxlength="80 " size="30 ">

      </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

      <td valign="top">

        <label for="telephone ">Telephone Number</label>

      </td>

      <td valign="top">

        <input type="text " name="telephone " maxlength="30 " size="30 ">

      </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

      <td valign="top">

        <label for="comments ">Comments *</label>

      </td>

      <td valign="top">

        <textarea name="comments " maxlength="1000 " cols="25 " rows="6 "></textarea>

      </td>

    </tr>


    <tr>

      <td valign="top">

        <label for="room">Room</label>

        <td valign="top">
          <select name="room">
            <option value="Ηλεκτρολογοι">Type room 1</option>
            <option value="Γεωπονοι">Tyre room 2</option>

          </select>


        </td>

        <td valign="top">




        </td>

    </tr>



    <tr>

      <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center ">





        <input type="image " src="buttononclick.png" alt="Submit Form " />

      </td>

    </tr>

  </table>

</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {



    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

    $email_to = "antonis997@gmail.com";

    $email_subject = "Your email subject line";





    function died($error) {

        // your error code can go here

        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

        echo $error."<br /><br />";

        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

        die();

    }



    // validation expected data exists

    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['email']) ||

        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||

        !isset($_POST['comments'])  ||

        !isset($_POST['room']))  { 

        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       

    }



    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required

    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required

    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required

    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $room = $_POST['room']; // not required



    $error_message = "";

    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {

    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    died($error_message);

  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }



    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Room: ".clean_string($room)."\n";





// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>



<!-- include your own success html here -->



Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.



<?php

}

?>
```

Comment: http://antonisem.eu/contact-en.html (i just updates with your suggestions but not working)

Comment: can you just help me with the form?

Comment: the return is =>  $error_message = "errrror1";
 
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

Comment: i just edited , but is not clear like before

Comment: i changed the errror1 to error . and it returns   We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. These errors appear below.

error

Please go back and fix these errors.

Comment: You did it ! Thanks a lot ! It's the time it's too late in Greece so i am not working properly , A BIG THANK YOU

Answer (score -1):

You forgot the name of the field.

```
<select name="room">
```